# PostgreSQL predicate `IS OF` and `IS NOT OF` supported or documented?

Tags: postgresql

[Reviewing some of the regression tests for PostgreSQL](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/test/regress/sql/with.sql#L72), I can see

```
SELECT x, x IS OF (text) AS is_text FROM q;
```

This apparently dates back to [7.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/release-7-3.html)

> Add IS OF / IS NOT OF type predicate (Thomas)

Is this form supported. In my own code, I would have written,

```
pg_typeof(x) = 'text'
```

But I like `IS OF` better.

Comment: I cannot find this in the docs, so I guess it's not _really_ supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not documented, yet, but it is certainly supported and should be moving forward. It's actually in the SQL 2011 spec as `type predicate`.

```
8.19 <type predicate>
Function
Specify a type test.

Format
<type predicate> ::=
<row value predicand> <type predicate part 2>

<type predicate part 2> ::=
IS [ NOT ] OF <left paren> <type list> <right paren>

<type list> ::=
<user-defined type specification>
[ { <comma> <user-defined type specification> }... ]
```