# Timezone offset displayed though it shouldn't be stored

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone

I new to Postgres and v9.6.3 on a Linux system.

From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-datetime.html) and the [PostgreSQL: Up and Running](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449326331) book, I learned that the timestamptz type just subtracts the offset of a timestamp on insertion and then just stores UTC on disk. The timezone information is 'lost' so to say.

Now I'm wondering how the psql client can display the timezone correctly despite that:

The following row was created by something like:

```
insert into table values ('1999-12-31T00:00:00+0100'::timestamptz, ...);
```

and is displayed as

```
select time from table;

          time          | field1 | field2 | 
------------------------+--------+---------
 1999-12-31 00:00:00+01 |      1 |       1 | 
...
```

and

```
select time AT TIMEZONE 'Europe/Berlin' from table;

          time          
---------------------
 1999-12-31 00:00:00
...
```

You can see in the first snippet that postgres seems to know the correct timezone from the insertion ('Europe/Berlin' which has +01h offset to GMT in winter) But how does this come?
I would have expected it do display UTC time.

Comment: What is the output of `SHOW TIMEZONE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bit simpler than I assumed. What we're seeing here is that the top is returning a `timestamp with time zone` in ISO 8601, with tz offset. The bottom, because you're using `AT TIMEZONE` is returning a `timestamp without time zone` in the time zone specified. It gets stringified  differently because the type is different and the timezone portion has been lost.

Using [`IS OF`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/181985/2639) to verify this.

```
SELECT now(),
  now() IS OF (timestamp without time zone) AS "timestamp without time zone",
  now() IS OF (timestamp with time zone) AS "timestamp with time zone",
  now() IS OF (timestamp) AS "timestamp";
              now              | timestamp without time zone | timestamp with time zone | timestamp 
-------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+-----------
 2017-10-05 15:24:58.479183-05 | f                           | t                        | f
```

(1 row)

```
SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago',
  now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago' IS OF (timestamp without time zone) AS "timestamp without time zone",
  now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago' IS OF (timestamp with time zone) AS "timestamp with time zone",
  now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago' IS OF (timestamp) AS "timestamp";
          timezone          | timestamp without time zone | timestamp with time zone | timestamp 
----------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+-----------
 2017-10-05 15:24:34.342588 | t                           | f                        | t
(1 row)
```

Thanks goes out to @johto on irc.freenode.net/#postgresql.

Answer (score 2):

From the [PostgreSQL documentation you link to](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-datetime.html), about halfway down the page:

> When a `timestamp with time zone` value is output, it is always converted from UTC to the current `timezone` zone, and displayed as local time in that zone. To see the time in another time zone, either change `timezone` or use the `AT TIME ZONE` construct.

So (as Evan Carroll hinted in his comment), if your system has 'Europe/Berlin' set as `timezone`, you would expect to see the UTC date/times output using that timezone.

To confirm, try inserting a date/time from another timezone; that should *also* be output showing the 'Europe/Berlin' time instead. Or, try changing `timezone`, and confirm that the dates that were showing the time from `Europe/Berlin` now show the time from the new time zone instead.